# Solving the Rosalind challenge "Finding a Motif in DNA"

Tags: r, bioinformatics, rosalind

The problem I am currently working on gives you a DNA string and a substring. You need to have your code output the start location of each instance of the substring in the DNA string. For ex;
given DNA string = "GATATATGCATATACTT"
substring = "ATAT"
output should be: 2 4 10
*this ex is what I am using to test my code*

Link to rosalind problem if you need: https://rosalind.info/problems/subs/

The code I currently have *almost* works correctly:

```
# Finding a Motif in DNA

input <- readLines("input.txt", warn = FALSE) # Load data

DNAseq1 <- input[1] # line 1 of data file is DNA string
substring1 <- input[2] # line 2 of data file is the substring being searched for

print(DNAseq1)     #
print(substring1)  # Test commands to make sure the lines are being assigned to the variables correctly

print(unlist(gregexpr(substring1, DNAseq1)))
```

The output it returns is:

```
[1] 2 10
```

*However,* it should output:

```
[1] 2 4 10
```

The DNA string is "GATATATGCATATACTT" and the substring is "ATAT", I believe it's not picking up location 4 (2nd instance of substring) due to it being in the middle of the first instance of the substring. I'm not sure how to fix this, please help!

Comment: Modify dupe like so: `gregexpr(sprintf("(?=%s)", substring1), DNAseq1, perl=TRUE))`